# Need help related with cluster setup

Tags: java, ejabberd

I am trying to make a cluster of ejabberd.For the same purpose i have configured the single node of ejabberd(i am using version 15.04 which is the latest one available)and now to add another node i am trying modify the configuration file.I opened the "/sbin/ejabberdctl" script file for changing the host name and modified the

ERLANG_NODE=ejabberd@localhost to ERLANG_NODE=ejabberd@ejabbered1

and modified the "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml" ERLANG_NODE=ejabberd@ejabbered1

Now when I try to run the ejabberd using "ejabberdctl start" i could see 
   Failed RPC connection to the node ejabberd@ejabberd1: nodedown

After going to the "ejabberd.log" i could see

"2015-05-20 06:10:21.462 [critical] <0.38.0>@ejabberd_app:db_init:120 Node name mismatch: I'm [ejabberd@ejabberd1], the database is owned by [ejabberd@localhost]"

Now i want to know how can i change the node name in change node name in Mnesia.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the node name associated with a Mnesia database. You either have to restart fresh or export the Mnesia database with old node name and reimport it. See: https://www.ejabberd.im/migrate-host

Note that setting up cluster should not involve changing node name, so I am not sure what you did to get to that state.

Comment: Hi,I followed the steps mentioned in article 4.5 in https://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#htoc82.The idea is to have multiple ejabberd servers on the same machine and setting up the cluster.As i will be installing the multiple servers of ejabberd so i have to keep the different names for each node.I have followed the steps mentioned in the link.but when i am trying to restore the back up files then it is giving me Can't install fallback from "/tmp/new.backup" at node ejabberd@localhost: {"Cannot install fallback",{"No disc resident schema on local node",[ejabberd@ejabberd1]}}